# How NOT to re-create activity after orintation in android?

Tags: android, listview, orientation

I have activity the contains a `ListView`, and this `listview` is filled with data from a web service in `onCreate()` function ( using `AsyncTask`). When the screen orientation changes the activity is re-created, I don't want that. how to keep saved after changing the orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this in the Activity in AndroidManifest.xml. Just adding "orientation" will not work on all devices.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your AndroidManifest.xml for the activity.

Comment: On honeycomb and above devices, you need to add `screenSize` to that `configChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answers suggest using `android:configChanges`, I would say this is really only a last resort option because it means resources for different orientations will not get loaded automatically.

Instead you should use the `onSaveInstanceState` or `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` functions of your activity. (If you use fragments, you should use `setRetainInstance` instead of the latter option.)

Another option would be to use a `ContentProvider` to store the data you download using the `AsyncTask` into a database so it wouldn't need to be re-downloaded anyway.

You should read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) for more information.

Comment: I disagree.  He's using an Async Task.  That means he absolutely needs to not have it destroyed, because the AsyncTask will NOT be destroyed with it and will continue to run, possibly causing crashes and memory leaks.   Of course I disagree and think the savedState is an uglier hack overall, but if you use AsyncTasks or Threads you MUST use configChanges.

Comment: Well, I would argue that he should be using the AsyncTask in a retained `Fragment` or a `Service`. Using `android:configChanges` is a hack in my eyes because it stops any orientation specific resources from being loaded, which, although may not be an issue in this context, it can be a real problem when making master-detail activities.

Comment: Creating a service, unless its meant to load data that spans activities, would be absolutely wrong here.  You're creating a completely unneeded Context and complexity.  Putting it in a Fragment wouldn't solve anything, as orientation changes would destroy the fragment as well, assuming its in the XML (which is the right way to do it).  The problem here is that Google made a horrible design decision with the whole destroy on rotation (and keyboard slideout, etc) thing, and we need to work around it.  You do that in the simplest way possible-  by turning it off.